# if else condition in ant task produces error

Tags: ant, build.xml, ant-contrib

I have a scenario where i need to move a directory from one location to another. If the same directory exists in the destination folder i need to rename the directory name as oldname_1.
So i wrote a snippet as follows:

```
<target name="Move">
    <IF>
        <available file="${output.dir}" type="dir" />
        <then>
            <echo message="Directory exists" />
            <rename src="${output.dir}" dest="${output.dir}_1"/>
            <property name="newdirectory" value="${dest}"/>
        </then>
    <ELSE>
        <echo message="Directory does not exist" />
    </ELSE>
    </IF>
        <move file="${newdirectory}" todir="C:\reports" />
    </target>
```

The error i am getting is :

```
Problem: failed to create task
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.
```

Comment: And have you added the necessary `<taskdef>`  for [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/)?  Remember that Ant doesn't have a native if/else construct built in.

Comment: Yes i have tried that also. Got another error saying "[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties. It could not be found."

Answer (score 2):

As [Ian Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18356332/368630) has already mentioned, you need the Ant-Contrib jar, and then setup the `<taskdef/>` to point to this jar. I highly recommend putting it inside your project and checking it into your version control system. This way, when someone checks out your project, they already have the Ant-Contib.jar *installed*.

My standard is to put all optional jars required for the build (not jars required for compiling) in the directory `${basedir}/antlib`, then put each optional jar in its own directory, so I would put `ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar` into `${basedir}/antlib/antcontrib`.

Then I define the task this way:

```
<property name="antlib.dir"      value="${basedir}/antlib"/>

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${antlib.dir}/antcontrib"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

This way, if you update the jar file to a new version of the Ant-Contrib jar, you simply plug it into the directory. You don't have to update the `build.xml`.

Also note that I use `net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml` and not `net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties`. The *XML* file is what you *should* use. The directions for this are on the [tasks page](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/index.html) and differ from the ones on the [main page](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) under the installation directions. The reason is that the XML file has the correct definition for the `<for>` task, and the *properties file* does not.

---

However, there is another way to do `if` and `unless` in Ant 1.9.1 without the need for optional jar files. These are the new [If and Unless entity attributes](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html).

These can be placed in all tasks, or sub-entities, and can usually replace the Ant-Contrib `if/else` stuff:

```
<target name="move">
    <available file="${output.dir}" type="dir"
        property="output.dir.exists"/>
    <echo message"Directory exists"
        if:true="output.dir.exists"/>
    <move file="${output.dir}" tofile="${output.dir}_1"
        if:true="output.dir.exists"/>
    <property name="newdirectory" value="${dest}"
        if:true="output.dir.exists"/>
    <echo message="Directory does not exists"
        unless:true="output.dir.exists"/>
    <move file="${newdirectory}" todir="C:\reports" />
</target>
```

Not so clean as your example. However, I would instead use the `if=` and `unless=` parameters on target names:

```
<target name="move.test">
    <available file="${output.dir}" type="dir"
        property="output.dir.exists"/>
</target>

<target name="move"
    depends="move.test, move.exists, move.does.not exists">
    <move file="${newdirectory}" todir="C:\reports" />
</target>

<target name="move.exists"
    if="output.dir.exists">
    <echo message="Directory exists" />
    <move file="${output.dir}" tofile="${output.dir}_1"/>
    <property name="newdirectory" value="${dest}"/>
</move.exists/>

<target name="move.does.not.exists"
    unless="output.dir.exists"/>
    <echo message="Directory does not exist" />
</target>
```

If you didn't echo everything, the structure would be a bit cleaner:

```
<target name="move.test">
    <available file="${output.dir}" type="dir"
        property="output.dir.exists"/>
</target>

<target name="move"
    depends="move.test, backup">
    <move file="${newdirectory}" todir="C:\reports" />
</target>

<target name="backup"
    if="output.dir.exists">
    <move file="${output.dir}" tofile="${output.dir}_1"/>
    <property name="newdirectory" value="${dest}"/>
</move.exists/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The if/else construct is not a native part of Ant out of the box, it is provided by the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) project, and you need to download a JAR and add the relevant `<taskdef>` to your build file.  For example, if you download [ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ant-contrib/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar) and put it in a directory named `build` in the same directory as your build.xml, then you can say

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="build/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```